# Calling recursive function in push_back

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, vector

I am writing a function to populate a vector in ascending order using values from a binary search tree. I am also trying to keep the run time of this function to O(n). I am thinking I will need to call a recursive function that traverses the bst and gets the numbers in ascending order. I am confused about how to use the results from the recursive function. Is it okay to use a recursive function inside of push back like this?

```
void vector_function(){
    std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int>(); 
    v.pushback(recursive_function(node *p));
}
```

for example if the Binary Search tree had values 5, 3, 4, 7 the resulting vector would have 3, 4, 5, 7

Comment: You would probably have a function return a `vector` of it's elements in inorder traversal instead of doing this. In short though, this would not work as you intend as `push_back` takes a single element to insert.

Comment: @Carl That would actually be practically O(N^2)  as the realocation cost of concatenating the child vectors would not benefit from push_back()'s guarantees. OP would be better served by passing the destination vector by reference to the recursive function.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you, was hoping that through the returns of the recursion one element would be passed to pushback at a time, definitely a long shot

Comment: @vince There is nothing special about recursive functions. It's just a name we give to functions that happen to call themselves.

Comment: I am still a little confused by the recursion aspect. Using the method of passing the destination vector to the recursive function, once I got to the desired value would it be proper to use v.pushback(val); recurssive_func(p->next); (i.e. store in vector THEN make the recursive call)?

Comment: @vince What's preventing you from just trying it out and seeing if it works? Once you  start coding it, you'll see that `p->next` makes no sense for a binary tree.

Comment: I am just new to c++11 and unsure of what I am "allowed" to do, but you're right I should just try it, thanks for the help! (I do know that p->next makes no sense, was just trying to write some example code quickly!)

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused about how to use the results from the recursive function. Is it okay to use a recursive function inside of push back like this?

I can think of two ways of doing that.

#### Option 1

Change `recursive_function` to also accept a reference to a `std::vector<int>`. Update its implementation to `push_back` elements to the vector appropriately.
Pass the vector to `recursive_function` when calling it.

```
void recursive_function(node* p, std::vector<int>& v)
{

    // When appropriate...
    v.push_back(p.data);
}
```

and use it as

```
void vector_function(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    recursive_function(p, v));
}
```

#### Option 2

Change  `recursive_function` to also accept a `std::function`.  Update its implementation to call the `std::function` with the value of the node appropriately. Use a lambda function that can be converted to a `std::function` that `recursive_function` accepts in the call to the function. Take care of calling `push_back` on the vector in the lambda function with the argument passed to it.

```
void recursive_function(node* p, std::function<void(int)> f)
{

    // When appropriate...
    f(p.data);
}
```

and use it as

```
void vector_function(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    recursive_function(p, [&v](int e) -> void { v.push_back(e); });
}
```

Comment: thank you! I think option 2 is a little bit advanced for me, but option 1 helps a lot!